# Hard Drive Read-Only, getting I/O Error

Tags: mount, hard-drive

since today, I can only read one of my hard drives on my Ubuntu NAS (`/dev/sdf`).

If I type `dmesg | less`, I get the following:

https://pastebin.com/QfPK7FC0 (Only excerpt, it continues like this).

```
blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdf, sector 2637873186
```

Is my hard drive dying or am I able to fix it with some commands?

Edit: After disabling Advanced Powermanagement and automatic acoustic management, the drive does not spin down so I was able to make a complete backup with ddrescue.
Going to wipe the hdd and reformat it and recheck SMART status and dmesg|less

Comment: Look up how to run a SMART test on the drive.

Comment: Already tried that, but I get the following error:
Short INQUIRY response, skip product id
A mandatory SMART command failed: exiting. To continue, add one or more '-T permissive' option

Comment: `sudo smartctl -a /dev/sdf`

Comment: Now after a restart, I get Pre-fail for Raw_Read_Error_Rate, Spin_Up_Time, Reallocated_Sector_Ct, Seek_Error_Rate, Spin_Retry_Count

So I guess I have to backup all my files as fast as possible and get a new Drive?

Comment: It's all the same sector, `2637873186` - is your disk misconfigured?

Comment: I don't know, how can I check that?